# Calling from multiple tables and inserting into one table

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, insert, multiple-columns

I am created a small quiz with some functionality and i've ran into a hiccup. I am trying to write into a answers table with information gathered from 2 different tables.

My Question would be is there a way to insert UserId, QuestionId and the answer from the code i  have below or can anyone help me with the code I have made.

Sorry if im abit of a noob. Code Below !

So far retrieve username from session

```
<?php
session_start();
//check if the user is already logged in.
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
}
?>
```

Then retrieve the QuestionId and userId and submit a answer

```
  <section id="content" class="content">

<form action="testingq.php" method="post">
<p>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "mydb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT QuestionId, QuestionText, InputTypeId FROM question";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<br> QuestionId: ". $row["QuestionId"]. " - : ". $row["QuestionText"]."<br>";
     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>  
<?php 

        $host="localhost"; // Host name 
        $user="root"; // Mysql username 
        $pass="root"; // Mysql password 
        $db_name="mydb"; // Database name  

        // Connect to server and select databse. 
        $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);


        $sql = "SELECT UserId FROM user WHERE username='$username'"; 

        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

        ?>
<input type="Radio" name="Answer" value="1" checked/>Yes</p>
<input type="Radio" name="Answer" value="0"/>No</p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Send it!"></p>
</form>

</section>
```

testingq.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>



    <?php 

            $host="localhost"; // Host name 
            $user="root"; // Mysql username 
            $pass="root"; // Mysql password 
            $db_name="mydb"; // Database name  

            // Connect to server and select databse. 
            $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);


            $sql = "INSERT into answers (QuestionId, UserId, Answer) VALUES(
            '$_POST[QuestionId]',
            '$_POST[UserId]',
            '$_POST[Answer]')"; 

            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

            ?>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Firstly, `$username` in your `where` clause should be quoted. That is likely a string. So, quote it if it is a string. However, `$username` is related to "root" in your DB connection; why?

Comment: thats the login for the local server ive got but its also the name inside the user table could you please explain what you mean in a code snippet.

Comment: It still needs to be quoted. It's a string and not an int.

Comment: As i said im abit of a noob i dont know where you mean its to be quoted. If you could attach some sort of code snippet that would be great.

Comment: `WHERE username='$username'";`

Comment: When i try submit it gives me these errors

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: QuestionId in C:\wamp\www\phpAdminSite\testingq.php on line 19
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0013 244936 {main}( ) ..\testingq.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: UserId in C:\wamp\www\phpAdminSite\testingq.php on line 20
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0013 244936 {main}( ) ..\testingq.php:0